# Binding the style property of all cells in a JavaFX TableView

Tags: javafx-2

I have a JavaFX TableView where each row should have a conditional style.

The styling is dependent on whether the source item of of the table row is present in a certain list or not.

This is what I have so far:

1) The data class that holds the data of a table row together with two boolean properties (true if the data is contained in list X) and a string property that should bind to the correct style attributes.

```
private class WebPageData {
    private WebPage page;

    private BooleanProperty isReferenced = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    private BooleanProperty isReferencing = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    private StringBinding style = new When(isReferenced).then("...").otherwise(...);
}
```

2) A change listener on table selection change that updates each boolean property accordingly, when the table selection changes

```
tblResultData.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Integer> arg0) {
            if (arg0.getList().size() == 0) {
                selectedPage.set(null);
            } else {
                // for coloring only consider the first selected row
                // multi select must be doable for certain other features
                WebPage selectedWebPage = tblResultData.getItems().get(arg0.getList().get(0)).page;
                selectedPage.set(selectedWebPage);

                // tableModel.data holds a list of data for every table row
                for (WebPageData data : tableModel.data) {
                    boolean referenced = selectedWebPage.getReferencedWebPagesList().contains(data.page);
                    boolean referencing = selectedWebPage.getReferencingWebPagesList().contains(data.page);

                    data.isReferenced.set(referenced);
                    data.isReferencing.set(referencing);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Now what I want to do is to somehow bind the style property of each table cell to the style property of WebPageData - so that the change listener updates the two boolean properties, therefore the style property of WebPageData is updated and in consequence the style of the table cell changes.

I tried to bind the style during creation phase by using a custom TableCellFactory, but of course this approach fails as there is no WebPageData instance present at this time. As the TableColumn classes don't provide an opportunity to iterate over all cells (so I could bind the style after the table actually gets its data), the only option I currently see is to keep a reference to each created table cell. I don't consider this solution is good practice.

So is there any other option to bind the cell styles? If I don't bind them, I have to set the styles manually each time the table selection changes - which puts me to the "I can't iterate over cells" problem again.

Answer (score 1):

```
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableRow;

public class HighlightBoundTreeTableRow extends TreeTableRow<Thing> {

    private static final String CHOSEN_STYLE_CLASS = "chosenStyle";

    private final ObjectProperty<Boolean> chosen = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    private final ChangeListener propertyChangeListener = (obs, ov, nv) -> updateHighlight();

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Thing item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        //cleanup
        getStyleClass().remove(CHOSEN_STYLE_CLASS);
        chosen.unbind(); // unbinding something that is not bound has no effect
        chosen.removeListener(propertyChangeListener); // also ok to remove a listener that was never there

        if (empty) {
            return;
        }

        chosen.bind(item.chosenProperty()); //bind will also set the intial value
        chosen.addListener(propertyChangeListener);

        updateHighlight();
    }

    private void updateHighlight() {
        if (chosen.get()) {
            getStyleClass().add(CHOSEN_STYLE_CLASS);
        } else {
            getStyleClass().remove(CHOSEN_STYLE_CLASS);
        }
    }
}
```

I know this was asked forever ago but maybe it'll help someone.

I had a similar issue I wanted to solve. I know you're using a TableCell and this involves a TreeTableRow but I believe the concept is the same: You want to change a field in your data object and have that change update the styling on wherever that object is being displayed in a table.

So I extended TreeTableRow and gave that class its own property field to hold on to. Every time that row is updated I unbind that property and rebind it to the field I want to listen to. (I do the same with the listener.) Since every time updateItem() is called it could be getting a different instance of my data object.

"chosenStyle" is just a class in my style sheet that changes the background color. Using classes instead of calling setStyle() makes it easier to remove the styling.